# The list [[a,b]|c] in Prolog

Tags: prolog

During my exploration of different ways to write down lists, I am intrigued by the following list `[[a,b]|c]` which appears in the book 'Prolog and Natural Language Analysis' by Pereira and Shieber (page 42 of the [digital edition](http://www.mtome.com/Publications/PNLA/prolog-digital.pdf)).

At first I thought that such a notation was syntactically incorrect, as it would have had to say `[[a,b]|[c]]`, but after using `write_canonical/1` Prolog returned `'.'('.'(a,'.'(b,[])),c)`.

As far as I can see, this corresponds to the following tree structure (although it seems odd to me that structure would simply end with `c`, without the empty list at the end):

[image: drawing of tree structure]

I cannot seem to find the corresponding notation using comma's and brackets though. I thought it would correspond to `[[a,b],c]` (but this obviously returns a different result with `write_canonical/1`).

Is there no corresponding notation for `[[a,b]|c]` or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: Well `c` is the *tail* of the "list". Although technically speaking, I would not call this really a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot seem to find the corresponding notation using comma's and brackets though.

There is no corresponding notation, since this is technically speaking not a real list.

Prolog has syntacical sugar for lists. A list in Prolog is, like a *Lisp* list, actually a linked list: every element is either an empty list `[]`, or a node `.(H,T)` with `H` the *head* and `T` the *tail*. Lists are not "special" in Prolog in the sense that the intepreter handles them differently than any other term. Of course a lot of Prolog libraries do list processing, and use the convention defined above.

To make complex lists more convenient, syntactical sugar was invented. You can write a node `.(H,T)` like `[H|T]` as well. So that means that in your `[[a,b]|c]`. We have an outer list, which has one node `.(H,c)` and the `?` is *another* list, with two nodes and an empty list `H = .(a,.(b,[]))`.

Technically speaking I would not consider this a "real" list, since the tail of a list should have either another node `./2`, or an empty list.

You can however use this with variables like: `[[a,b]|C]` in order to unify the tail `C` further. So here we have some sort of list with `[a,b]` as first element (so a list containing a list) and with an open tail `C`. If we later for instance ground `C` to `C = []`, then the list is `[[a,b]]`.

Comment: Thanks! I just got confused if this was an actual list as it was part of an exercise in the chapter about lists.

Answer (score 4):

As others have already indicated, the term `[[a,b]|c]` is **not** a list.

You can test this yourself, using the `|` syntax to write it down:

```
?- is_list([[a,b]|c]).
false.
```

You can see from `write_canonical/1` that this term is identical to what you have drawn:

```
| ?- write_canonical([[a,b]|c]).
'.'('.'(a,'.'(b,[])),c)
```

In addition to what others have said, I am posting an additional answer because I want to explain how you can go about finding the reason of **unexpected failures**. When starting with Prolog, you will often ask yourself "Why does this query *fail*?"

One way to find *explanations* for such issues is to *generalize* the query, by using logical *variables* instead of concrete terms.

For example, in the above case, we could write:

```
?- is_list([[A,b]|c]).
false.
```

In this case, I have used the logical variable **A** instead of the atom `a`, thus significantly generalizing the query. Since the generalized query *still* fails, some constraint in the remaining part must be responsible for the unexpected failure. We this generalize it further to narrow down the cause. For example:

```
?- is_list([[A,B]|c]).
false.
```

Or even further:

```
?- is_list([[A,B|_]|c]).
false.
```

And even further:

```
?- is_list([_|c]).
false.
```

So here we have it: **No term** that has the general form `'.'(_, c)` is a list!

As you rightly observe, this is because such a term is not of the form `[_|Ls]` where `Ls` *is* a list.

---

**NOTE:** The declarative debugging approach I apply above works for the **monotonic** subset of Prolog. Actually, `is_list/1` does not belong to that subset, because we have:

```
?- is_list(Ls).
false.
```

with the declarative reading "There is no <s>spoon</s> list." So, it turns out, it worked only by coincidence in the case above. However, we could define the intended *declarative* meaning of `is_list/1` in a pure and monotonic way like this, by simply applying the inductive definition of lists:

```
list([]).
list([_|Ls]) :- list(Ls).
```

This definition only uses pure and monotonic building blocks and *hence* is monotonic. For example, the most general query now yields actual lists instead of failing (incorrectly):

```
?- list(Ls).
Ls = [] ;
Ls = [_6656] ;
Ls = [_6656, _6662] ;
Ls = [_6656, _6662, _6668] .
```

From pure relations, we expect that queries work in *all* directions!

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation about how to use variables to gradually generalize; I will keep it in mind for the future! I was still wondering, however, if there is some kind of 'list' with the most important built-in predicates in Prolog? I know that you can check all of them through manuals, but I thought that perhaps there was some kind of useful 'synthesis' of them.

Comment: For beginners, I recommend you restrict yourself to the following built-ins: `true`, `false`, `(=)/2`, `dif/2` and CLP(FD) constraints like `(#=)/2`. These suffice to describe all interesting relations and are all pure and monotonic. Later, you can gradually use other predicates. Note that the declarative debugging approach I showed above works for the pure and monotonic subset of Prolog, so I recommend you restrict yourself to that subset.